# SSL_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION when attempting to debug with IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, firefox, iis

Created a new template ASP.Net Core 3.1 MVC web app. When I attempt to debug it using IIS Express I get the following error in firefox:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to localhost:44354. Peer using
> unsupported version of security protocol.
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION

I attempted to delete all of my localhost certificates with MMC, repair IIS Express to install a new one. When attempting to debug it asks me to trust the certificate, I press yes, but this error still appears.

I am on windows 7 if that matters.

Comment: are you accepting TSL 1.2?

Comment: I am unsure how to check

Comment: I have basically the same error in Firefox (though in the console it claims to be a CORS error) and in Chrome, where it's called `net::ERR_SSL_OBSOLETE_VERSION`. I am on Windows 7 and have successfully run the same code .NET 5 app on Windows 10, so it might be related to Windows 7. The .NET 5 server (based on Host.ConfigureWebHostDefaults i.e. Kestrel) is not showing any warnings.

Answer (score 29):

As far as I know, this issue is related with Firefox, the firebox doesn't support the tls 1.0 and tls 1.1.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could try below solutions:

1. Enter `about:config` into the firefox address bar (confirm the info message in case it shows up) & search for bold preferences starting with security.
2. Set `security.tls.version.min` (from 2 to 1)

Answer (score 17):

I was having that same issue in Firefox, after checking the answer of Brando Zhang, I try only changing the `security.tls.version.enable-deprecated` to true (in `about:config`) and it worked!

That way, you don't have to lower the TLS security version

Comment: I wish Firefox had an "Accept the risk and continue" option for this so I don't have to lower the security **for my entire browser** in order to view my server's management page :/